How Can Digon’s Be Viewed/Projected in 4D Space?
So, since you can project $x$D shapes on $x-1$D surfaces, such as the cube shape net and the tesseract shape net. I was wondering how could you project a digon (a 2 sided polygon (similar to a beach ball), only within curved space) in 4D space, as the base shape is “already” in 3D? Would it involve something similar to this a digon with lines wrapping all around a spheroid?
